# RHEL not starting anymore on vmware

Tags: vmware, rhel7

My computer kept rebooting lately showing me the blue screen while I was working on RHEL 'n vmware.

The last time the computer had reboot when I turned it on again and tried to work on RHEL here's what I have.

Did anyone of you face the same problem already ?

Thanks

---

In essence, the error is:

```
dracut-initqueue[217]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
[...]
dracut-initqueue[217]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[217]: Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/5b757528-cc16-4ff0-819d-805c908d9b35 does not exist 
    Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/5b757528-cc16-4ff0-819d-805c908d9b35 does not exist 

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exist the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot 
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.
```

EDIT: after [@Naushad Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9501117/naushad-ahmad)'s comment:

```
# chroot /mnt/sysimage/
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash' : No such file ordirectory
# cat /etc/fstab

# cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
cat: /boot/grud2/grub.cfg: No such file or directory
# ls /boot
initramfs-3.10.0-693.cl7.x86_64.img
# _
[anaconda] 1:main* 2:shell 3:log 4:storage-log 5:program-log      Switch tab: Alt+Tab | Help: F1
```

But the thing is when I start the rescue mode I ve that error message :
`You don't have any Linux partitions.`

[image: capture of the problem]

[image: test for naushad]

Comment: Avoid posting picture: how can you copy/paste the content to try to help you?

Comment: Please post the output of :

1. cat /etc/fstab

2. cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

3. ls /boot

Comment: @nicolallias can you please tell me how I can c/c the content without posting pics ?

Comment: That's very simple: I read what is on the picture and manually re-copy the stuff. This way, no need for anyone to do it again (saving time for us all). Keep this as a good practice, for it witnesses that you tried to search for the errors.

Comment: Alright, thank's a lot and all apologies for the disturbance